# using p:fileUpload with AJAX

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces **p:fileUpload** to transfer images to the backing bean as per the manual like so:

```
                <h:outputLabel value="Select Files:" />
                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{uploadImage.doUpload}"
                                  multiple="true"
                                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                                  description="Select Images"                                      
                                  update="@form"
                                  />
```

The component allows the user to select a number of files to upload in a batch, which is really convenient.   However before storing them in the data base I want the user to type in more information (i.e. an image title) so the **doUpload()** method takes the uploaded files and saves them to a property named **work** which is a list of objects.

Later in the page (inside the same **h:form**) I have a data table that shows the uploaded files that need to be processed.

```
                <p:dataTable
                    value="#{uploadImage.work}"
                    var="unit"
                    resizableColumns="true"
                    rendered="#{not empty uploadImage.work}">
```

The problem is that the data table is only redrawn once, no matter how many files get uploaded.  The **doUpload()** method gets called each file.  So when I click the **Upload** button on the component the **p:dataTable** appears, but only has one row in it no matter what.  If I refresh the screen all the rows appear.

Is there any way to re-render the **p:dataTable** each time **doUpload()** exits?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, the bean is view scoped, right?

Comment: @BalusC No it is is request scoped bean, with the the work property stored in the session map.   I attempted to use the flash map, but for some reason that doesn't work here.  That's different subject though.  (I can't use view scoped because I am using CDI to build my beans.)

Comment: Oh, perhaps you stored the uploaded files in the session scope the wrong way?

Comment: @BalusC As I noted, if I do a refresh page on the browser, the data table then has all the objects that I expect to see.  Even more so, since I was forced to use session scoped instead of flash, I can leave the screen and come back later and the objects are all there.   So I am not concerned about the persistence of the objects I am trying to display.

Comment: Hello @BalusC i want model=true attribute in <p;fileupload> that attribute is not provided by primefaces  in <p:fileupload> component..  give me your any suggestions

Comment: Any solution ? I also having this problem.  cant update client side component from uploadListener method.

Comment: @AhmedRaaj I don't recall how this was resolved it has been too many years.  Primefaces has had a lot of updates since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use primefaces [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf) component to update your datatable on the server side. e.g.

```
  public void myFileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event){
   //All your processing goes here
   RequestContext reqContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  //get your hands on request context
   reqContext.update(":form:myDatatable"); //update the datatable for each execution

  }
```

Comment: That is fascinating but it didn't work for me.  Looking at the Primefaces documentation it should have, but what I think is happening is that I am only getting one AJAX response after the first upload but none after that.  I'll continue poking at this but thanks for the hint.